# wordpress/php: create an upvote button that does not refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Beginning developer here, making a website using wordpress as a platform. I would like the user to be able to click an upvote button and upvote a post without refreshing the page. I figure I should probably use javascript to highlight the button once clicked as well as change the vote number. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to run a php script (to update the database) without refreshing the page.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Probably JQuery and Ajax is what you're looking for. Whit Jquery's `$.ajax()` function you'll be able to download sites async.

Answer (score 1):

sample upvote php for posts add this to your functions file....

```
add_action('wp_ajax_upvote', 'upvote');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_upvote', 'upvote');

function upvote() {
   $postid= $_POST['id'];
   $direction = $_POST['direction'];
   $votes= get_post_meta($postid, '_votes', true);

   if($direction='down') {
      $votes--;
   } else {
      $votes++;
   }

   update_post_meta($postid, '_votes', $votes);
   echo $votes;
   exit();
}
```

The above needs security like any form submit of $_POST variables. Dont leave these out in your code!!

jQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.arrow').click(function(){ //if your upvote has class arrow?
        //you need someway of passing postid to here!
        //if you want up / downvote -- logic needed here, if not remove direction from below!

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",

           data: {
              action: 'upvote',
              id: id,
              direction: direction //remove if not needed
           },

           success: function (output) { //do something with returned data

              console.log(output);
              jQuery('#postupvote').text(output); //write to correct id - maybe use postid in the id of the vote count on the page e.g. id="vote23" jQuery('#vote'+postid)
        }


        });
    });

})
```

google wordpress ajax for more information

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. I am a little confused by the snippet about security. Can you expand a little bit on that. I have other forms that are posting data and I did not implement security. Thanks.

Comment: security means escaping and validating user inputs to prevent malicious code being uploaded and also nounces + keys ... http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753 http://devotepress.com/wordpress-coding/data-validation-and-sanitization-wordpress/#.VAbFWvldXw8